# how to replace particular value in column using R

Tags: r

Below is the data set for reference X1

```
X1 <- data.frame(A = c(2,3,4,5,6,7),
                 B = c(0,0,0.23,1.7,2.45,84.5))  
#  A     B
#1 2  0.00
#2 3  0.00
#3 4  0.23
#4 5  1.70
#5 6  2.45
#6 7 84.50
```

Now i need to replace values greater than 0 as 1

```
#  A B
#1 2 0
#2 3 0
#3 4 1
#4 5 1
#5 6 1
#6 7 1
```

Comment: Try `X1$B <- ifelse(X1$B > 0, 1, 0)`

Comment: Lots of different ways to do this, but I personally like replace: `df$B <- replace(df$B, df$B>0, 1)`

Answer (score 1):

With:

```
X1$B <- as.integer(X1$B > 0)
```

The result:

```
> X1
  A B
1 2 0
2 3 0
3 4 1
4 5 1
5 6 1
6 7 1
```

Comment: @MichaelChirico No, he said "greater than 0 as 1".

Answer (score 0):

So your data.frame is:

```
X1<-data.frame(A=2:7,B=c(0,0,0.23,1.7,2.45,84.5))
```

and you want to replace all the values greater than 0 in the column B with 1. Use can use the standard built-in sub-replace function of '[<-', i.e.:

```
X1[X1[,"B"]>0,"B"]<-1
```

i.e. check if the values in the column B are greater than zero and if true replace them with 1.